# Substring of Variable in R, then group by it

Tags: r

I am attempting to group some data by month based on a substring grouping value `Jan` of `Jan.05` for example so I can determine a monthly average and I am having a mental block on parsing and grouping it appropriately.

For other operations I have the data in a couple of forms.

- Original data: Item with value across 5 years in a single row
- Reshaped version of the entire data set
- Subsetted data for each item

What I ultimately want to do is a average price per month for each food item.

This is giving me the same value for every month.

```
bcn_avg_prc <- ddply(bacon, .(substring(bacon$variable,1,3),value), summarise,
             avg_price = mean(bacon$value, na.rm = FALSE))
```

So my question is:

> How to I then turn it into a new data table with average by month as I obviously can't just do a `mean(data$variable)` as it would do it for the entire set, not grouped by the new sub-string variable?

The end result I am desiring will look something like this, and I do not care which data set it comes from.

```
ItemA  Jan 4.06
ItemB  Jan 2.32
ItemC  Jan 3.23
...
ItemA  Feb 4.09
...

> head(steak)
    Item variable value
3  Steak   Jan.05 5.168
13 Steak   Feb.05 5.258
23 Steak   Mar.05 5.292
33 Steak   Apr.05 5.390
43 Steak   May.05 5.398
53 Steak   Jun.05 5.272

> head(meat)
         Item variable value
1 Ground Beef   Jan.05 2.712
2  Beef Roast   Jan.05 3.784
3       Steak   Jan.05 5.168
4       Bacon   Jan.05 3.367
5   PorkChops   Jan.05 3.215
6         HAM   Jan.05 2.242

> head(MeatPrice)
         Item Jan.05 Feb.05 Mar.05 Apr.05 May.05 Jun.05 Jul.05 Aug.05 Sep.05
1 Ground Beef  2.712  2.754  2.759  2.775  2.752  2.735  2.719  2.715  2.731
2  Beef Roast  3.784  3.908  3.951  3.799  3.809  3.783  3.670  3.619  3.600
3       Steak  5.168  5.258  5.292  5.390  5.398  5.272  5.059  4.987  4.900
4       Bacon  3.367  3.395  3.355  3.331  3.560  3.457  3.478  3.442  3.404
5   PorkChops  3.215  3.180  3.200  3.209  3.232  3.306  3.271  3.280  3.254
6         HAM  2.242  2.253  2.273  2.350  2.335  2.301  2.323  2.304  2.358
```

Comment: 1) for substring, you need to give the start and end `substring(meat$variable, 1, 3)`, 2) which of these data sets do you want to use? in your desired output, there is no grouping by year, are you just taking the mean by month regardless of year?

Comment: @rawr Yes, I do not care about the year in my output. Just eventually the mean price by month of each commodity. As far as data set, I do not care, what ever is the simplest as any of the three could be used.

Comment: @rawr That helped.. edit the question to just be about grouping using the substring.

Comment: Which of the above datasets is this question about? I would actually recommend splitting the variable so that you still retain all of the information.

Comment: you may also want to store the data in `Date` format (see `?as.Date`) from which it's quicker to extract months

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `substring`/`substr`, you need to give the starting/ending position:

```
substr('Jan.05', 1, 3)
# [1] "Jan"
```

There are many ways to do the split/apply/combine thing in r:

```
meat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Item variable value
1 GroundBeef   Jan.05 2.712
2  BeefRoast   Jan.05 3.784
3       Steak   Jan.05 5.168
4       Bacon   Jan.05 3.367
5   PorkChops   Jan.05 3.215
6         HAM   Jan.05 2.242")

meat$variable <- substr(meat$variable, 1, 3)

meat$avg <- with(meat, ave(value, list(Item, variable), FUN = mean))
aggregate(. ~ Item + variable, data = meat, mean)
by(meat, list(meat$Item, meat$variable), function(x) mean(x$value))
with(meat, tapply(value, list(Item, variable), mean))
```

since you seem to be using ddply, you could do this

```
library('plyr')
ddply(meat, .(Item, variable), summarise, avg = mean(value))

#        Item variable value
# 1      Bacon      Jan 3.367
# 2  BeefRoast      Jan 3.784
# 3 GroundBeef      Jan 2.712
# 4        HAM      Jan 2.242
# 5  PorkChops      Jan 3.215
# 6      Steak      Jan 5.168
```

Comment: I see how the first one works great, the second one calculates average.. but should I still need another step after ddply to get the exact output you got?

Comment: @CRSouser oh my mistake, I forgot the summarise

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that since you're already using "plyr", you can consider a combination of "dplyr" and "tidyr" to do something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

meat %>%
  separate(variable, into = c("Month", "Year")) %>%
  group_by(Item, Month) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value))
```

---

Actually, if you are starting with your "MeatPrice" table, you can do it all with something like:

```
MeatPrice %>%
  gather(var, val, -Item) %>%
  separate(var, into = c("Month", "Year")) %>%
  group_by(Item, Month) %>%
  summarise(val = mean(val))
# Source: local data frame [54 x 3]
# Groups: Item
# 
#          Item Month   val
# 1       Bacon   Apr 3.331
# 2       Bacon   Aug 3.442
# 3       Bacon   Feb 3.395
# 4       Bacon   Jan 3.367
# 5       Bacon   Jul 3.478
# 6       Bacon   Jun 3.457
# 7       Bacon   Mar 3.355
# 8       Bacon   May 3.560
# 9       Bacon   Sep 3.404
# 10 Beef Roast   Apr 3.799
# ..        ...   ...   ...
```